Patch Tuesday installs successfully, but then re-installs every time I Check for Updates after attempting to leave Windows Insider Preview
I'm in an InTune managed environment (AzureAdJoined to Entra). Months ago, my update ring was changed from General to Pre-release - Windows Insider. That caused some driver compatibility issues and was reverted to General Availability.
Since leaving Windows Insider, every Patch Tuesday delivered through Windows Update installs successfully and reboots as required. Subsequently, Check for Updates re-downloads and re-installs (though never reboots) that month's Patch Tuesday update.
I've tried the Windows Update Troubleshooter which reports finding some unspecified issue but does not fix the problem. I've also done (and do fairly regularly):
chkdsk.exe /scan C:

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

sfc /scannow

With no detections.
This is my registry build information:
(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' | Select-Object ProductName, ReleaseId, CurrentBuild, CurrentBuildNumber, CurrentVersion, DisplayVersion, EditionID)

ProductName        : Windows 10 Pro
ReleaseId          : 2009
CurrentBuild       : 22631
CurrentBuildNumber : 22631
CurrentVersion     : 6.3
DisplayVersion     : 23H2
EditionID          : Professional

I would like to stop this cycle because it demonstrates something is not consistent in Windows Update. Any ideas?

You cannot just simply leave Windows Insider depending on the build and channel, going back to the Release channel, might take months until the next stable release (i.e. 24H2) is released. Did you actually migrate those 22H2 installs to a Windows Insider preview build or did you simply attempt to patch 22H2 with patches that were not applicable to 23H2 and the patches failed to install.  [Edit] your question to include this necessary information.

@Ramhound That was my suspicion (wasn't my decision to join WI in the first place). Does that imply that I'm still receiving insider builds, or that my system is just inconsistent until the 24H2, and I'll have to live with it? (Windows Update packages don't show "- Insider Preview" in their names; current looping one is 2024-09 Cumulative Update for Windows 11 Version 23H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5043076)).

What channel was configured? KB5043076 would not be applicable a build for 24H2 or a build beyond 24H2. KB5043076 was released this week so it's not a preview release channel build.

@Ramhound I'm fairly certain Enable Pre-relase Builds : Windows Insider Release Preview was chosen, then I was put back onto Not configured reverting my ring to Servicing channel: General Availability channel. This was deactivated about 4 months ago, so I'm still in 23H2.
